# Add div to parent with absolute position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one parent div with style position relative and couple divs inside that div with style absolute like

```
<div id="container" style="position:relative;width=400px;height=400px;">
<div style="top:20px;left:20px;width:20px;height:20px;"></div>
<div style="top:40px;left:40px;width:20px;height:20px;"></div>
<div style="top:60px;left:60px;width:20px;height:20px;"></div>
</div>
```

How to add new div to div with `id="container"` with `top="0px" left="0px"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#container').append(
    $('<div/>').css({top:'0px',left:'0px'})
);
```

Here's a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/AWYbD/

Answer (score 2):

first, be careful to set "position: absolute" to your inner divs. This is not implicitely set when using the top, left, etc declarations.

To add a new div (I assume using jquery),

just do

```
$('#container').append('<div style="position:asbolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;"></div>');
```